# insert a CSV file with polygons into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv, geometry, gis, polygon

I've got a CSV file including 3 columns named boundaries,category and city.
the data in every cell,below the column "boundaries" is comprised of something like this:

```
{"coordinates"=>[[[-79.86938774585724, 43.206149439482836], [-79.87618446350098, 43.19090988330086], [-79.88626956939697, 43.19328385965552], [-79.88325476646423, 43.200029828720744], [-79.8932647705078, 43.20258723593195], [-79.88930583000183, 43.211150250203886], [-79.86938774585724, 43.206149439482836]]], "type"=>"Polygon"}
```

how can I create a table with a proper data type for column "boundaries"?

Answer (score 0):

The data you have specified is in JSON format, so you could either store the `boundaries` data as a `jsonb` table column.
e.g: `CREATE TABLE cities ( city varchar, category varchar, boundaries jsonb)`

The alternative is to parse the JSON and store the coordinates in a PostgreSQL ARRAY column: something like:

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
    city varchar,
    category varchar,
    boundary_coords point ARRAY,
    boundary_type varchar
)
```

Comment: One thing to check - in JSON you've provided, the `coordinates` value contains a nested array with the `[ <latitude>, <longitude> ]` pairs; is there only ever 1 array here? If there are multiple boundary arrays in other records, a single `boundary_coords` array property won't be enough - you may need to look at using a child table to allow you to store multiple `coordinates` lists. Depending on your needs, it would also be worth looking at using PostGIS's `geometry` or `geography` type for your coordinates - see https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography

Comment: Actually,I need to insert a CSV file which has a boundary column full of polygons (just like the code above) into a database. I wrote the following code but it didn't accept both jsonb and json format.
      create table city24(boundaries jsonb, category varchar, city varchar);
and then 
       copy school24(boundaries,category,city) from 'C:/test.csv' DELIMITER ',' 
       CSV HEADER;
and here's the error:
       ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "=" is invalid.

Should I use MangoDB?

Comment: the sign " => " makes it odd and confusing to me.

Comment: Apologies, I missed the `=>` where in JSON it would be `:`. I'm guessing its a serialized PHP object? You may be able to just find/replace the "=>" with ":" before importing - does that work?

Comment: yes,I did replace it with : manually in the csv file and then it was accepted.thanks